# Compare data from two workbooks separate from operating workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm basically working out of three workbooks. The first is thisBook, the one running the macro and eventually what the data should be set into. The second is Reporting, which holds a set of data imported from a TXT file that periodically appends with data from another process I have running. The third is WeeklyData which is pulled from an Access database into excel as a single sheet and represents data I get once a week.

The program generates a report in Column A of thisBook that should display any entries in WeeklyData that were not included in Reporting. Basically if the process I run didn't use something from the data I get weekly. I'm having some difficulty because every time I try to run it I get a "Application-defined or object-defined error". Unfortunately it's not telling me what the error is, but the Reporting book is the one that's active when that happens.

```
Sub Find_Matches()

Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
Dim ReportingRange As Variant

Dim thisBook As Workbook
Set thisBook = ThisWorkbook

Dim Match As Boolean

Dim Weekly_Data As Workbook
Set Weekly_Data = Workbooks.Open("Weekly Data.xlsx")

Dim LastRow As Long

Dim Reporting As Workbook
Set Reporting = Workbooks.Open("Reporting.xlsm")

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

Set CompareRange = Weekly_Data.Worksheets("Sheet1")._
    Range("b2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").End(xlDown)).Value
Set ReportingRange = Reporting.Worksheets("Sheet1")._
    Range("a1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Value

For Each x In CompareRange
    Match = False
    For Each y In ReportingRange
        If x = y Then Match = True
        If x = y Then Exit For
    Next y
    'If Match = False Then x.Offset(0, 1) = x
    LastRow = thisBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    If Match = False Then x.LastRow
Next x

Weekly_Data.Close
Set Weekly_Data = Nothing
Reporting.Close
Set Reporting = Nothing

Exit Sub
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code more closely, there are several problems. I fixed them in the code below (note - for simplicity I am putting the three lots of data in one sheet but you can put your own workbook structure back, obviously)

```
Sub Find_Matches()

Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant
Dim ReportingRange As Variant

Dim thisBook As Workbook
Set thisBook = ThisWorkbook

Dim Match As Boolean

Dim Weekly_Data As Workbook
Set Weekly_Data = ActiveWorkbook '<<<< changed for simplicity. Change back to what you need
' Dim LastRow As Long  <<< no longer used

Dim Reporting As Workbook
Set Reporting = ActiveWorkbook  ' <<<< ditto

' <<< new: set the first cell where output goes once, then move down when you write in it >>>
Dim outputRange As Range
Set outputRange = thisBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2") ' pick whatever the right spot is

On Error GoTo Errorcatch

Set CompareRange = Weekly_Data.Worksheets("Sheet1"). _
    Range("b2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b2").End(xlDown))  ' <<< not .Value

Set ReportingRange = Reporting.Worksheets("Sheet1"). _
    Range("a1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1").End(xlDown))  ' <<< not .Value

For Each x In CompareRange
    Match = False
    For Each y In ReportingRange
        If x = y Then Match = True
        If x = y Then Exit For
    Next y
    If Match = False Then
      outputRange.Value = x
      Set outputRange = outputRange.Offset(1, 0) ' <<< so outputRange always points to next empty cell
    End If
Next x

Weekly_Data.Close
Set Weekly_Data = Nothing
Reporting.Close
Set Reporting = Nothing

Exit Sub
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

These changes made the code working for me. Incidentally I recommend that you turn off `On Error` statements when you are trying to debug, so you stop in the line where the error occurs (instead of just reporting the error). Once your code is working, you turn the error trapping on to keep things going in unexpected circumstances.

There are a few places where this can be further cleaned up, but I thought for a first VBA project you had really got a lot right already so I didn't want to over criticize.

Comment: As I tried to defined in the line above (but clearly didn't do a great job), what I'm attempting to do is take the value stored in X and move it to thisBook at the first available cell in column A.

Comment: While that did definitely make those lines of code cleaner (which I needed, thank you) its unfortunately still throwing the same error. My assumption was that I had done something wrong in setting the values of CompareRange and ReportingRange using a range of cells and .value

But like I said, I'm pretty new to VBA so I'm not sure.

Comment: Open the VBA editor and run the code from there. You should be able to see the line where the error occurs. Report back.

Comment: That's the interesting thing, I have been the whole time. After I hit "ok" on the error it returns the cursor to the same line it was on as before (checked multiple times by changing cursor location) and no areas highlighted. Again, the Reporting sheet is the one that's on the screen when the error pops up, and minimizes when "ok" is hit.

Comment: Aaaah! Turn off the `On Error` statement (comment it out), then you will see where the error is really occurring!

Comment: Thanks for all your work on this. The macro runs as it should. I still ran into problems trying to get this to calculate from multiple sheets (even 2, to be honest) but what I'm going to do is import all the data into one page and do the calculations there. Thanks again for all your help.